# JQuery AutoComplete suggession box showing previous record while change country

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, autosuggest

I have used automplete by using php code.

I need to show my zip code by country wise. But my older country zip code is showing. Please see screenshot -

**Pic-1**

[image]

**Pic-2**

[image]

There have two different images.

`Pic-1` I have selected county and zipcode is working fine. All the zipcode is showing in the `USA` count. When I select `UK` my zipcode is not working. It is showing previus zipcode which I was searching before for `USA` country(see `Pic-2`).

Please help me and fix my issue.

my Code -

```
        $(function() {
            var pageUrl = document.getElementById('pageurl').value;
            $('#zip_business').autocomplete({
                serviceUrl: pageUrl + "businesses/ajax.php", 
                extraParams: {
                    country: function() {
                        return $('#country').val();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

**ajax.php**

```
//$sqlData = $this->Zipcode->find("all", array('conditions' => array('Zipcode.zip LIKE' => $query . "%"), 'fields' => array('Zipcode.zip', 'Zipcode.full_state', 'Zipcode.city')));
$sqlData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM zipcodes WHERE zip LIKE '".$_REQUEST['q']."%' AND country='".$_REQUEST['country']."'");
$values = '';
while ($getData = mysql_fetch_array($sqlData)) {
      $values.=$getData['zip'] . "," . $getData['full_state'] . "," . $getData['city'] . "|" . $getData['zip'] . "\n";
}
echo $values;
```

Comment: what is happening when you select 3rd country ?is it showing first country's value or second contry's value ?..And have you written code on onchange event for your country dropdown ??

Comment: I have 3 countries `USA`, `UK` and `Canada` I have selected second country. But it is showing `USA` country zip-codes. Basically this same Zip-code `755...`. I saw ajax not firing. for this zip

Comment: If I search again with new number which I have not entered before. Then it works fine. I got my correct Zip-code

Comment: Can you show me how are you calling auto complete for this textbox ?

Comment: I have posted my code.